# ASP.NET MVC3 Deploy Script Missing

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-3

Getting error when deploy Asp.NetMVC3 project to IIS. 
All scripts reference are missing.

At console log 
*NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/Content/js/Content/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js*

```
<script src="../../Content/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also this way getting error.

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this you can use these two ways

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<head>
   <script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
   @RenderSection("JavaScript", required: false)
</head>
```

**_SomeView.cshtml**

```
@section JavaScript
{
  <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/SomeScript.js")"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("/Scripts/AnotherScript.js")"></script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using absolute path

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("/Content/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```